# SQL - efficient way to aggregate boolean values (postgresql)

Tags: sql, performance, amazon-redshift

Let's assume table with 3 columns (originally it's a big table): id, is_deleted, date.
I have to check if given id's are deleted or not and create new column with this value (TRUE or FALSE).
Let's simplify it to below table (before):

| id | is_deleted | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | False | 03-07-2022 |
| A | True | 04-07-2022 |
| B | False | 05-07-2022 |
| B | False | 06-07-2022 |
| C | True | 07-07-2022 |

(after):

| id | is_deleted | date | deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | True | 03-07-2022 | TRUE |
| A | False | 04-07-2022 | TRUE |
| B | False | 05-07-2022 | FALSE |
| B | False | 06-07-2022 | FALSE |
| C | True | 07-07-2022 | TRUE |

So we can see that row with ids A and C should have True value in new column.
For given id could be more than one TRUE value in is_deleted column. If any id has at least one TRUE value, all rows with given id should be deleted (TRUE value in new column).
I need to do it inside this table, without group by, cuz by choosing group by, I have to create another CTE to join it with and it complicates a problem and performance.

I want to just create single column inside this table with new `deleted` value.

I've found bool_or function, but it won't work with window functions in redshift, my code:

```
bool_or(is_deleted) over(partition by id) as is_del
```

I can't use max, sum functions on boolean.
Casting bool to int worsens the performance.
Is there any other way to do it using booleans and keep good performance?

Thank you.

Comment: As for the formatting of the table, for some reason Stackoverflow shows it working fine in the preview, but unless you have a blank line before and after the table, it will show up as a garbled mess when you submit. I've edited your question to add that blank line. Hope Stackoverflow fixes that one soon. It's been broken since they introduced table markup.

Comment: Would both rows of `A` have a `is_del` value of `True`, or just the one row with `is_deleted` = `True`? It's not clear to me. Perhaps sharing Desired Results after this operation is complete would help clarify.

Comment: Yes, both can have TRUE. If there's one ore more TRUE value for given id, it should be deleted.

Comment: I edited problem, to be more precise.

Comment: The documentation for the MAX window function states "Accepts any data type as input. Returns the same data type as expression.".  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_MAX.html  Are you saying that the documentation is incorrect?

Comment: Also at the beggining you have:
"The MAX window function returns the maximum of the input expression values. The MAX function works with numeric values and ignores NULL values."
So I believe it works with any NUMERIC data like int, float, etc.
When I want to do it with boolean I got:
"function max(boolean) does not exist. You may need to add explicit type cast"

Answer (score 4):

It should be possible to emulate such behaviour with `MIN/MAX` functions and explicit casting:

```
SELECT MAX(is_deleted::INT) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
FROM ...;
-- if all is_deleted are false, then result is 0, 1 otherwise
```

If the result should be boolean, then: `MAX(is_deleted::INT) OVER (PARTITION BY id) = 1` or `( MAX(is_deleted::INT) OVER (PARTITION BY id))::BOOLEAN`

Comment: Its's how I did it. Is it a good approach to do double casting in such case?
Or is there better option, cuz of better performance.

Comment: @Joe I would not expect significant performance implications

Answer (score 1):

From me here is 2 diffrent way you could check:

1.With EXISTS, which work very well in very redundant table

```
SELECT
    id
    , is_deleted
    , date
    , NVL((SELECT 'TRUE' FROM dual WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourtabletable yt2 WHERE 
        yt2.id = yt1.id 
            AND yt2.is_deleted = 'True')
    ), 'FALSE') deleted
FROM 
    yourtabletable yt1;
```

2.With WITH where you could use hint's like /*+ materialize */

```
WITH tmp AS(
    SELECT /*+ materialize */ id, 'TRUE' deleted FROM yourtabletable WHERE is_deleted = 'True'
)

SELECT
    id
    , is_deleted
    , date
    , NVL((SELECT deleted FROM tmp yt2 WHERE 
        yt2.id = yt1.id 
            AND yt2.is_deleted = 'True'
    ), 'FALSE') deleted
FROM 
    yourtabletable yt1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem, then I would think that for each unique `id` value you should be looking at the `is_deleted` value that has the latest (maximum) date value. In this way even though there may be a row where `is_deleted` is true, if there is another row for the same `id` value with a later date that has `is_deleted` as false, then false should be the final status. If this isn't how the new `deleted` column should be computed, then just ignore this answer, please.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v15)**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("id" varchar(1), "is_deleted" bool, "date" timestamp)
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    ("id", "is_deleted", "date")
VALUES
    ('A', False, '2022-03-07 00:00:00'),
    ('A', True, '2022-04-07 00:00:00'),
    ('A', True, '2022-04-09 00:00:00'), /* another True row for A */
    ('B', False, '2022-05-07 00:00:00'),
    ('B', False, '2022-06-07 00:00:00'),
    ('C', True, '2022-07-07 00:00:00')
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
with lastest_is_deleted as (
    select t.* from
        (select t.id, t.is_deleted as deleted, row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum
            from Table1 t
         ) t
    where seqnum = 1
)

select t.*, l.deleted from
Table1 t join lastest_is_deleted l on t.id = l.id;
```

| id | is_deleted | date | deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | false | 2022-03-07T00:00:00.000Z | true |
| A | true | 2022-04-07T00:00:00.000Z | true |
| A | true | 2022-04-09T00:00:00.000Z | true |
| B | false | 2022-05-07T00:00:00.000Z | false |
| B | false | 2022-06-07T00:00:00.000Z | false |
| C | true | 2022-07-07T00:00:00.000Z | true |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d5FZSTGSszDM9LM9p1R4vh/0)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the approach with which you can get all records with their respective deleted column values.

```
   select a.*,case when  b.id is not null then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as deleted 
from table1 a  left join  (select distinct id from table1  where is_deleted is true) b  on (a.id=b.id) order by 1,3;
```

I have created sample schema here :https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4k32Eb1t2DSUQ6FkzKBMXi/0
Feel free to customize it with your data.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
("id" varchar(1), "is_deleted" bool, "date" timestamp);

INSERT INTO Table1
    ("id", "is_deleted", "date")
VALUES
    ('A', False, '2022-03-07 00:00:00'),
    ('A', True, '2022-04-07 00:00:00'),
    ('A', True, '2022-04-09 00:00:00'), /* another True row for A */
    ('B', False, '2022-05-07 00:00:00'),
    ('B', False, '2022-06-07 00:00:00'),
    ('C', True, '2022-07-07 00:00:00')
;
INSERT INTO Table1
    ("id", "is_deleted", "date")
VALUES
    ('D', False, '2022-03-07 00:00:00'),
    ('D', false, '2022-04-06 00:00:00');
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    ("id", "is_deleted", "date")
VALUES
    ('C', False, '2022-03-07 00:00:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think using `UNION ALL` of 2 sub queries could yield better performance than using window functions, especially if your table have index on `id` and `is_deleted` columns.

```
SELECT 
  d1.*,
  TRUE AS deleted
FROM <your table> d1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM <your table> d2
              WHERE d1.id = d2.id AND is_deleted)
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
  d1.*,
  FALSE AS deleted
FROM <your table> d1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM <your table> d2
              WHERE d1.id = d2.id AND is_deleted);
```

See demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d5FZSTGSszDM9LM9p1R4vh/2)

Answer (score -1):

This select statement should give the needed output:

```
select
   yt1.id,  
   yt1.is_deleted,
   yt1.date,
   case when yt2.is_deleted then true else false end as deleted
from yourtabletable yt1
left join yourtabletable yt2 on yt2.id = yt1.id and yt2.is_deleted
```

Comment: In addition to a missing comma and ambiguous column names, if there were, for example, anther row with values `('A', False, '2022-03-09 00:00:00'), /* another False row for A */`, then you would be returning duplicate rows.
`

Comment: oops I corrected the ambiguous names, and added the (missing) comma.

Comment: See [this demo of the third issue](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a008a8/1), which might be a possibility though the data the OP shows is not clear on that issue. But I wouldn't make any assumptions.

Comment: Adding `DISTINCT` solves that. But I (choose) not to add that to my statement in the answer (because it's unknown if that can happen in the questioned problem)

Comment: So *I* posted a question to the OP asking whether it is possible to have such a row, which is better than hiding one's head in the sand.

Comment: OP is hiding that in his question.... 

Comment: I just noticed that the third comment posted to the OP's question posted by the OP says that having two such True rows is possible.